# Create a sub folder using google-drive-api and return the id with PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I can create the sub folder just fine with the code below but I just can't return the id.

I would like to get the id and/or the link to the folder so I can add them to my database.

Currently the below creates the folder but just returns "//" as the id!

Thanks for your help

```
<?php

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

$file = new Google_DriveFile();

//Setup the Folder to Create
$file->setTitle('Project  Folder');
$file->setDescription('A Project Folder');
$file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');

//Set the ProjectsFolder Parent
$parent = new Google_ParentReference();
$parent->setId('0B9mYBlahBlahBlah');
$file->setParents(array($parent));

//create the ProjectFolder in the Parent
$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
));

// print_r($createdFile);
print "folder created sucessfully";
echo "folder id is" . $createdFile->id;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is very helpful. But your methods are wrong. I think they have updated their api....

Comment: I like this question, calling the list function subsequently does work but is inpractical. It would be nice to have a way, that returns the id directly from the inital call, as it happens when uploading a file with uploadType=resumable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not fancy way but this is my method to get folder ID:

```
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$files = $service->files->listFiles();
foreach ($files['items'] as $item) {
    if ($item['title'] == 'your_folder_name') {
        $folderId = $item['id'];
    break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = $service->files->listFiles(array('maxResults' => 1));
var_dump($files['items'][0]['id']);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I think methods has been updated so i have used new methods. [Here is the library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

```
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
      $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
      $file->title = "New File By Bikash 111";
      // To create new folder
      $file->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');


      // To set parent folder
      $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
      $parent->setId('0B5kdKIFfgdfggyTHpEQlpmcExXRW8');
      $file->setParents(array($parent));

      $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

      // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
      $client->setDefer(true);
      $request = $service->files->insert($file);

      // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
      $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
      $client,
      $request,
      'text/plain',
      null,
      true,
      $chunkSizeBytes
      );
      $media->setFileSize(filesize(TESTFILE));

      // Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
      // complete.
      $status = false;
      $handle = fopen(TESTFILE, "rb");
      while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
      }
      //Here you will get the new created folder's id
      echo "<pre>";
      var_dump($status->id);
      exit;
}
```